# GwtChosen not playing well with GWT LayoutPanel and RootLayoutPanel

Tags: gwt, gwtquery, layoutpanels

I am using GwtChosen 1.1.0 and GwtQuery 1.3.3. It seems to play nice only with RootPanel widgets and not RootLayoutPanel widgets.

Is being not usable with RootLayoutPanel a known limitation with GwtChosen?

Sample Code and screenshots below. Notice RootLayoutPanel sample hides the drop down for the GWTChosen widget within stack and thus leaves it unusable.

```
public void onModuleLoad() {
    if ( !ChosenListBox.isSupported() )
    {
        $( "#browserWarning" ).show();
    }

    ChosenListBox chosen = new ChosenListBox( true );
    // init default place holder text
    chosen.setPlaceholderText( "Choose your favourite chart..." );
    chosen.setWidth( "300px" );
    chosen.setMaxSelectedOptions( 4 );
    chosen.addChosenChangeHandler( new ChosenChangeHandler()
    {
        public void onChange( ChosenChangeEvent event )
        {
        }
    } );
    chosen.addGroup( "Simple" );
    chosen.addItemToGroup( "line" );
    chosen.addItemToGroup( "bar" );
    chosen.addItemToGroup( "pie" );
    chosen.addItemToGroup( "area" );

    //StackPanel stackpanel = new StackPanel();
    //stackpanel.add(chosen, "Choose");
    //stackpanel.add(wrapper, "Charts");
    //stackpanel.setHeight("150px");
    //RootPanel.get().add(stackpanel);

    StackLayoutPanel stackLayoutPanel = new StackLayoutPanel( Unit.EM );
    stackLayoutPanel.add( chosen, "Choose", 2 );
    stackLayoutPanel.setHeight( "150px" );
    RootLayoutPanel.get().add( stackLayoutPanel );
}
```

[image]
[image]

Comment: @manolo Am i doing something silly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Never used GwtChosen but it definitely looks like a [know issue](https://github.com/jDramaix/gwtchosen/issues/5), although relative to `DockLayoutPanel` and not `RootLayoutPanel`. There is also an attached workaround, that maybe useful.